# Why are $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ continuous on $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have seen many calculus books to use the limits $\lim_{x\to0}\sin x=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0}\cos x =1$ without their proofs. Are these limits obvious? I think no. These two limits are essentially telling us that the functions $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are continuous at $x=0$. But how do we know this?

In fact, it is a standard result that $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are continuous (and differentiable too) on $\mathbb R$. Again, I have no clue about its proof.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity. If you can show either is differentiable at any point, then it is indeed differentiable at zero, and hence continuous. This is easy by use of the trigonometric identities.

Comment: You need to say how you define sine and cosine as functions before you can prove facts about them. There are a number of (equivalent) ways of defining them, and the tools required to prove their continuity will depend on the definitions you are using. (Same is true for $e^x$ and the logarithms, for that matter)

Comment: Note that $$
\left| {\sin x - \sin y} \right| = 2\left| {\cos \left( {\frac{{x + y}}{2}} \right)} \right|\left| {\sin \left( {\frac{{x - y}}{2}} \right)} \right| \le \left| {x - y} \right|
$$ since $|\sin t|\le |t|$ and $|\cos t|\le 1$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$. Similarly for $\cos$.

Comment: There are no holes, sharp points, or asymptotes on the graph, therefore it is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to overcome such difficulty consists in defining the trigonometric functions as power series. More precisely, one has that:
\begin{align*}
& \sin(x) := x - \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{5}}{5!} - \frac{x^{7}}{7!} + \ldots\\\\
& \cos(x) := 1 - \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{4}}{4!} - \frac{x^{6}}{6!} + \ldots 
\end{align*}

Hence the proposed limits make sense (as well as continuity and differentiability).

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove it...

Let us use epsilon-delta definition of continuity to prove this...

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ , then

$$|f(x)- f(0)| < | \sin x -0| < |x| $$

($\because$ in $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ , $|\sin x| < |x| $)

So , let's take. $\delta= \epsilon $ then we can say that whenever $|x-0|<\delta$ then

$$|f(x) - f(0)|=|\sin x| <|x|< \delta=\epsilon$$

So, limit exist at $0$ and equal to value of function.

Hence, $\sin x $ is continuous at $x=0$.

Here I have given the proof for $\sin x$ only you can similarly prove that $\cos x$ is also continuous at $x=0$ by finding appropriate $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$. Use the formula $(1-\cos x)= 2\cdot \sin^2 (\frac{x}{2})$ for further calculation.

You can also prove that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ both functions are continuous.